# Coupled Oscillation Simulation

Tags: classical-mechanics, soft-question, software, oscillators

I'm looking for an online coupled oscillation simulation. The best I have got so far is this ---

https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/normal-modes/normal-modes_en.html

But I'm looking for something which has more options like changing the mass of the objects, changing the spring constants, cutting off the springs.

Please suggest if you have come across better simulations.

PS : I apologize if this question does not belong here. I need a coupled oscillation simulator for my work.

Comment: Depending on your programming skills, you can download the [jar file](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/normal-modes/) and modify the code yourself. As far as I know, PhET is open-source under the GPL, so you're free to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but its the same link that I posted.

Comment: Strange. When I click on the link I provided, I go to a page listing a bunch of HTML and JAR files.

Comment: Its just a bunch of same things in different languages.

Comment: JAR files are Java Archive files. You can download it, unzip it (may require changing the file from `.jar` to `.zip`), then edit the appropriate files as necessary.

Comment: I have code for simulating large coupled spring systems in Mathematica. Is this for teaching?

Comment: Hey @DumpsterDoofus it's for an experiment in my lab --- for a better understanding of my subject --- flies. It's not for any commercial purpose.